# Problem to compare array in PowerShell and copy it

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a

1. List of data in csv and I need to compare it again a set of array.
2. And then I need to copy the whole data and then insert into new set of array.

Sample data in CSV

```
ID  VersionLabel     Created     Author     Modified           Editor    FileLeafRef     Title   Remarks     Business_x0020_Unit     DE_Department   Record_x0020_Disposition_x0020_Date     Note    
1   0.6    02/11/2020 03:21:12   John     02/11/2020 03:21:12   John     fields.csv  Test1   Test111    Finance              Department A       02/10/2020 23:00:00                 notes    
1   0.5    02/10/2020 11:16:39   John     02/10/2020 11:16:39   John     fields.csv  Test1   Test111    Marketing        Department A old       02/10/2019 23:00:00             notes old    
1   0.4    02/10/2020 10:28:54   John     02/10/2020 10:28:54   John     fields.csv  Test1   Test111    Sales                Department A old       02/10/2019 23:00:00             notes old
1   0.3    02/10/2020 09:29:31   John     02/10/2020 09:29:31   John     fields.csv  Test1   Test111    Sales                Department A old       02/10/2020 23:00:00                 notes old
1   0.2    02/10/2020 09:28:35   John     02/10/2020 09:28:35   John     fields.csv  Test1   Test111    Sales                Department A old       02/10/2020 23:00:00                 notes old
```

Set of Arrary that I have

```
ID
VersionLabel
Created
Author
```

which basically i got using following code

```
$FinalReport = Import-Csv $OriginalReport -Delimiter ","
$Header = $FinalReport[0].psobject.properties.name
$FinalReportGrouped = $FinalReport | Group-Object {$_.ID} |Foreach-Object {
            $_.Group | Sort-Object VersionLabel -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
}
```

The problem is, I'm not able to come out with the proper logic on how to compare the set of array.

Example, below is the code to compare it..

```
foreach ($row in $FinalReportGrouped) 
        {
            $FinalReport | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $row.ID} | Foreach-Object {   
                    #I need to compare here, if the value inside $ is not equal $header array
                    if($_.value -ne $header)
                    {
                         # and then I need to copy whole content of $row into $_ variable, below code seems got problem. I can copy if using $_.Department = $row.Department, but I need to get it dynamically. 
                         $_ = $row #this is wrong maybe..
                    }

                }

        }
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question? Something that can be used to illustrate what the input is and what the actual and desired output should be. Also, see the help about [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thank you for your comment boss..and i have added some info there. Actually i'm quite stuck on compare the value inside array dynamically..

Comment: It seems your _set of array_ only contains the first four headers of the CSV. The rest of the question makes no sense to me at all I'm afraid. What are you trying to compare and what is your desired output?